# Angular Bootstrap: data-provide="datepicker" not using format identifier

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Please consider this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/N9l1hyloZezZb7GMjqAH?p=preview).

I have a controller set up like this:

```
app.controller("myController", [
      "$scope",
      function($scope){
        $scope.DateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";

        $scope.From = '15/01/2015'; // DD/MM/YYYY
        $scope.To = '31/12/2015'; // DD/MM/YYYY
      }]);
```

And usage at Html level is:

```
<input type="text" 
    ng-model="From" 
    data-provide="datepicker" 
    date-format="DateFormat" />
```

Regardless of the format identifier, the date is provided as `MM/DD/YYYY`, which would cause errors on the backend.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "date-format" attribute used in the datepicker elements should be changed to "data-date-format" and assigning "DateFormat" using template in the element, that is, `data-date-format={{DateFormat}}` and also the date format must be changed to "dd/mm/yyyy".
modified plunker for your reference,
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ep7LcJHpssFb4vnZXdC6?p=preview Hope it helps.

script.js:

```
$scope.DateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy";
```

index.html:

```
<input type="text" 
    ng-model="From" 
    data-provide="datepicker" 
    data-date-format={{DateFormat}} />

  <input type="text" 
    ng-model="To" 
    data-provide="datepicker" 
    data-date-format={{DateFormat}} />
```

bootstrap-datepicker reference:
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html

Comment: I like this, this is more the proper AngularJS way of doing things. Why is it `data-date-format` in this case, not `date-format`?

Comment: formats vary depending on the plugin we use in our code. Based on the docs provided for this plugin its "data-date-format". If we use some other libraries it will change. For ex, angular-bootstrap-ui datepicker uses "uib-datepicker-popup" attribute for formatting date.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are binding string value ('15/01/2015') to angular $scope variable, you can't get desired output. In order to do it, I have changed your plnkr a bit. I hope you will not mind with it.

updated working   http://plnkr.co/edit/PRbDW1g1JmmkUb7T7NJr?p=preview

You need to go with this, (bootstrap datepicker)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.myDP').each(function(){
                                        $(this).datepicker({
                                           format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                                           autoclose: true
                                        });;
                        });

        });
   </script>
```

you controller would have below code,

```
       var fromDate=new Date(2015,00,15);
        var toDate=new Date(2015,11,31);
        $scope.From =$filter('date')( fromDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'); // DD/MM/YYYY
        $scope.To = $filter('date')( toDate,'dd/MM/yyyy') ; // DD/MM/YYYY
```

Please find the solution and let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: Looks like that works, but how can I set the datepicker from the controller? Would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can set format using `uib-datepicker-popup` attribute.

```
 <input type="text" 
    ng-model="From" 
    data-provide="datepicker" 
    date-format="DateFormat"
    uib-datepicker-popup="DD/MM/YYYY" />
```

Comment: Could you update the Plunk please? I see no difference.

Comment: use this boostrap library for angular, where those problems are solved,https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/